# Logical view = component diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

Is the components diagram (UML) a logical view of the system?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on who you are asking

1. A developer
2. A project manager
3. A business analyst
4. A system administrator
5. The client

I would say **NO** but I am just a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Components diagram is used to describe the structure of the system. Helps more to model the physical aspect of an OO software system.

Answer (score 0):

UML has been designed for object modeling purposes. Is this object approach logical for you ? If yes then UML is logical and all its diagrams :-)